# adding title to jqdialog confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery-dialog

How can i add a title to a jqdialog confirm box?
I have a message that needs to displayed in the center and the title should be displayed on top.
Currently i am getting my message displayed on top with no default title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a title to the title attribute of the div containing your dialog

```
<div class="demo">  

    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Whatever you title is....">     

        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
    </div>

</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/swaff/cQfJW/)